# Image Processing Java esp.Slicing

Tags: slice

im trying to convert an android code into java using netbeans as IDE.
all the other conversion is done. a single line is still remaining because i don't know what equivalent function can be use here.

```
public BufferedImage[] SeprateText(BufferedImage newb3)
{
    Color clr1,clr2,clr3,clr4;
    for(int iht=0;iht<newb3.getHeight()-1;iht++)
    { 
        if(chk==false)
         {
            clr1 = new Color(newb3.getRGB(0, iht));
            if(clr1==Color.RED)
             {
                 chk=true;
             }
         }  
         clr2 = new Color(newb3.getRGB(5, iht));
         clr3 = new Color(newb3.getRGB(5, iht));
         if(chk && ( clr2 == Color.BLACK || clr3 ==Color.WHITE ))
         {
             if(!sind)
             {
                  sind=true;
                  index[count]=iht;
             }

            location[count]++;
            clr4 = new Color(newb3.getRGB(0, iht+1));
            if(clr4==Color.RED)
            {
                chk=false;
                endloc[count]=iht;

                 barray[count] = Bitmap.create(newb3,0,index[count],
                                newb3.getWidth(),location[count]);
```

// this is the line. i dont know what function of bufferedImage can replace it

```
                 count++;
                 sind=false;
           }
        }

      }


}
```